# Redirecting All Apache Traffic to HTTPS Behind a Load Balancer

Tags: apache2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

How do you configure an Apache site to redirect all http traffic to https while behind a load an AWS balancer?

There are a lot of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883226/apache-https-to-https-redirection) that don't involve a load balancer.

I'm using this configuration to get redirect working without the load balancer:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin sysadmin@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/html

    AllowEncodedSlashes On

    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Log real IP since we're behind a load balancer.
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!forwarded
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log proxy env=forwarded

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [L]

    # Redirect all non-https traffic to https.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly and redirects all traffic to https.

However, when I put the server behind a current generation AWS load balancer, Apache correctly redirects but responds with the error page:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

In my logs, I'm seeing the error:

```
 AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/html
```

This doesn't make any sense, since access is fine without the load balancer. What's going on?

Comment: I read somewhere that sometimes people have problems if they use `!https` as the condition, rather than `=http`. Not sure if that will help you. I am using `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http` on a new load balancer and it works for me.

Comment: Hey @Cerin, have you tried querying the Apache server setting up X-Forwarded-Proto header to see how it behaves? something like `curl -I -H "X-Forwarded-Proto=https"`. Maybe it's not seeing that particular config line. Hope that helps.