# Redirect from HTTPS to HTTPS of other website

Tags: redirect, https, httpd.conf

I have read some other questions which are doing almost the same stuff but I wasn't able to replicate the same.

https://serverfault.com/questions/167395/redirect-https-to-another-https

[Apache HTTPS to HTTPS Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883226/apache-https-to-https-redirection)

(I have tried both)

When users click or enter the https:// version I want to redirect my website (which is https://website1.com) to another website (https://website2.com).

What I have achieved till now is when the user clicks on http://website1.com version of the site, they are getting redirected to https://website2.com but when https://website1.com it loads the https://website1.com, no redirection happens.

I'm using Apache HTTPD and below is my httpd.conf file entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerName website1.com
    ServerAlias www.website1.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RedirectPermanent / https://website2.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't remember Apache config but what you show is only for port 80 which is http only.

Comment: I think virtual host is only responsible for directing the traffic. If you’re able to help and for that need any other snippet you can tell me. :443 port code doesn’t have any other server name I have checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems **OR** condition is missing for HTTP.

The following code should work, although I haven't tested it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
   ServerName website1.com
   ServerAlias www.website1.com
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} [OR]
   RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP} on
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   RedirectPermanent / https://website2.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same.